# using parameterized function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel. The route is as:

```
Route::get('/imagess','cont@imagess');
Route::get('/imagess/details/{id}','cont@image_details');
```

the functions inside the controller files are:

```
public function imagess() {
        return view('imagess');
    }
    public function image_details($id) {
        return view('image_details');
    }
```

the view file is `imagess.blade.php`

```
@extends('inside.main')
@section('content')

<img src="{{asset('images/play.png')}}" height="100px" width="100px"><a href="{{url('imagess/details/1')}}">View image 1</a><br>
<img src="{{asset('images/eat.png')}}" height="100px" width="100px"><a href="{{url('imagess/details/2')}}">View image 2</a><br>
<img src="{{asset('images/sleep.png')}} height="10px" width="10px""><a href="{{url('imagess/details/3')}}">View image 3</a><br>
tihsajf
<img src="{{asset('images/read.png')}}" height="100px" width="100px"><a href="{{url('imagess/details/4')}}">View image 4</a><br>

@endsection
```

What should be my `imagess_details.blade.php` to display basic details of each of those images? I am not trying to display exact details using database. just displaying anything. for eg. display 'hello' if i click image1, 'begineer' if i click image2, 'here' if i click image3 and so on..

if i make `images_details` as follows. it displays 'hello' whether i click image1, image2, or any other image.

```
@extends('inside.main')
@section('content') 

<h2>hello</h2>

@endsection
```

Comment: Why does “imagess” have two ‘S’s, and why are you not using StudlyCased names for your controller and action names?

Comment: `images_details` will always display "Hello" because its static? You need to pass something from your controller to the view.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're asking about transferring data from controller to the view:

```
public function image_details($id) {
    $images = Images::all(); // get information about all images from database
    return view('image_details')-with('images', $images); // transfer data to the view
}
```

The view gets all data inside $images collection, now you can iterate and get data:

```
@foreach ($images as $image) // iterate all images
    <img src="{{ $image->src }}" alt="{{ $image->altText }}" height="100px" width="100px"><a href="{{ $image->link }}">{{ $image->name )}}</a><br>
@endforeach
```